# Convert text to CSV for json deserialization

Tags: c#, json, csv

I have the following content of a txt file, actually here is the original link:
http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/570/scripts/items/items_game.9e449667cd3ba55c9c545c2a4a1825da541057b0.txt

```
"items"
{
    "default"
    {
        "name"      "default"
        "hidden"        "1"
        "item_class"        "dota_item_wearable"
        "item_name"     "#TF_Default_ItemDef"
        "item_slot"     "weapon"
        "item_quality"      "normal"
        "min_ilevel"        "1"
        "max_ilevel"        "1"
    }
    "20887"
    {
        "name"      "Level 1000 Compendium"
        "prefab"        "misc"
        "creation_date"     "2015-08-14"
        "expiration_date"       "2016-05-01 00:00:00"
        "image_inventory"       "econ/tools/aegisholder"
        "item_description"      "#DOTA_Item_Desc_Level_1000_Compendium"
        "item_name"     "#DOTA_Item_Level_1000_Compendium"
        "item_rarity"       "immortal"
        "item_type_name"        "#DOTA_WearableType_Relic_of_Prestige"
        "static_attributes"
        {
            "cannot trade"
            {
                "attribute_class"       "cannot_trade"
                "value"     "1"
            }
            "cannot delete"
            {
                "attribute_class"       "cannot_delete"
                "value"     "1"
            }
        }
        "used_by_heroes"        "0"
    }
    "15323"
    {
        "name"      "Gem of Taegeuk"
        "prefab"        "socket_gem"
        "creation_date"     "2013-10-16"
        "disable_style_selector"        "1"
        "image_inventory"       "econ/tools/samtaegeuk"
        "item_description"      "#DOTA_Item_Desc_Gem_of_Taegeuk"
        "item_name"     "#DOTA_Item_Gem_of_Taegeuk"
        "item_rarity"       "rare"
        "item_type_name"        "#DOTA_WearableType_Relic_of_Prestige"
        "static_attributes"
        {
            "gem type"
            {
                "attribute_class"       "gem type"
                "value"     "3"
            }
            "cannot trade"
            {
                "attribute_class"       "cannot_trade"
                "value"     "1"
            }
            "gem quality"
            {
                "attribute_class"       "gem quality"
                "value"     "14"
            }
        }
        "used_by_heroes"        "0"
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert this to CSV file so that I could easily convert CSV to JSON and do deserialization and populate my class with attributes and values from this textual file that is data value format.

I have the following code that is parsing the txt file:

```
Treenode rarities = root.Child["items_game"];
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("items_game.csv");
                    sw.AutoFlush = true;
                    RecursiveReadSchema(rarities, sw, 0);
```

And

```
private static void RecursiveReadSchema(Treenode rarities, StreamWriter sw, int depth)
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Treenode> n in rarities.Child)
            {
                //csv = "," + n.Key;
                string csv = new String(',', depth) + n.Key + "\n";
                if(n.Value.Data.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in n.Value.Data)
                    {
                        csv += Environment.NewLine + "," + keyValuePair.Key + "," + keyValuePair.Value;
                    }
                }

                sw.WriteLine(csv);
                RecursiveReadSchema(n.Value, sw, depth + 1);
            }
        }
```

My problem is the part of "static_attributes", they are not placed on proper place in CSV file so as its elements. Now if anybody knows a better way of converting this txt file to JSON directly I would go even for that solution but I didn't find anything online. For now, I am trying to parse this txt as treenode and then treenode to CSV file from there to JSON and from JSON to my class.

KVParser class that I used is from here: http://pastebin.com/C9t3y3H7

Thanks,

EDITED:

With this line:

```
SchemaResult schemaResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SchemaResult>(result);
```

Here is my class SchemaResult:

```
protected class SchemaResult
{
    public Schema Items_game 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Schema
    {
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public Dictionary<string, Item> Items
        {
            get;
            set;
        } 

        public class Prefabs
        {
            [JsonProperty("item_class")]
            public int Item_Class
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            [JsonProperty("item_type_name")]
            public string Item_Type_Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string Prefab { get; set; }

            public string Item_Type_Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string Item_Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string item_rarity { get; set; }

            public string item_description
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string Item_Slot
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public PriceInfo Price_Info
            {
                get; set;
            }
        }

        public class PriceInfo
        {
            public string category_tags
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public int price
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        protected class SchemaResult
        {
            public Schema Items_game 
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you convert the file to CSV if JSON is what you want? As far as I can see the text file is almost JSON. A line with only a 'key' is an object. Such a line is followed by a line with a curly brace. After that one or more attributes (two 'keys') or objects (one 'key' again) or an object end (closing curly brace) follow.

Comment: I tried directly to use this txt file for a JSON deserialize but every time it fails. Here is the reason why: "Could not cast or convert from System.String to SteamTrade.Schema+SchemaResult." You can see my SchemaResult class in edited question.

Comment: Of course it fails. It is not valid JSON. So you have to convert it to valid JSON first. But instead of converting it to CSV and then to JSON I suggest to convert it to JSON immediately.

Comment: I know its not valid, it is value data format. Can you point me out where to look for converting it to JSON immediately?

Answer (score 2):

To convert that string into valid JSON, you just need to tweak it a little bit.

You can do that with three regex replaces:

```
var json = Regex.Replace(
               Regex.Replace(
                   Regex.Replace(
                       Regex.Replace(data, @"""(\r?\n\s*\{)", @""":$1"),
                       @"(})(\r?\n\s*"")", @"$1,$2"),
                    @"""(\r?\n\s*\"")", @""",$1"),
                 @"""\s+""", @""": """);
```

`data` contains your original data as shown in your question. Then we perform the following transformations:

1. We add a colon to the end of lines that are followed by curly braces
2. We add a comma to the end of lines that are followed by a quote
3. We add a comma to the end of lines that end with a curly brace and are followed by a quote
4. We add a colon in between two quotes

Comment: Very nice. Exactly what I meant.

Comment: 4. We need to put curly braces around it?

Comment: I already tried that, manual not with regex just to see if it is going to pass. But still I am getting an error: Error converting value "items_game" to type 'SteamTrade.Schema+SchemaResult'. Path '', line 1, position 12. I've used your code as suggested but when I am doing a DeserializeObject this exception occurs. @DanielHilgarth

Comment: The problem is that now it is missing only a comma after every closed curly brace. Can you help me how to combine that with your Regex code? @DanielHilgarth

Comment: Added another replace to add the missing commas.

Answer (score 0):

If the quasi-JSON is as regular as in your example, and if you don't mind using command-line tools to convert the quasi-JSON to JSON, you could easily use awk, or some combination such as sed and any-json.  The following works for your sample (assuming quasijson.txt is the input file):

```
$ sed -e '/"/s/"/":/2' -e 's/}/},/' quasijson.txt |\
  sed -e '1s/^/{/' -e 's/" *$/",/' -e '$s/$/}/' |\
  any-json -format=json5
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by adding comma after every "}" + additional Regex code that Daniel provided. Textual file was after that converted into JSON format without problems and read also. Even though this added comma on all places after "}" - closed curly brace, it works.

Thanks for helping everyone.